# What operations are supported for automatic differentiation in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

I am confused with what types of operations are supported for automatic differentiation in tf. Concretely, is tensor indexing operation as follows supported?

```
...
# feat is output from some conv layer and the shape is B*H*W*C

# case one
loss = feat[:,1:,1:,:] - feat[:,:-1,:-1,:]

# case two
feat[:,1:,1:,:] = feat[:,1:,1:,:]/2. # assign and replace part original value
loss = tf.reduce_sum(feat)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn'ta direct answer, but as a clue, this automatic differentiation library [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) lists operations that are not supported, see [Non-differentiable functions](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/c6f630a5ec18bd30f1485bc0dbbccb8664c77510/autograd/numpy/numpy_vjps.py#L13), for example `floor()`, `round()` are not auto differentiable.

One can also define their own operations, provided if you can code the gradients yourself, see [extend-autograd-by-defining-your-own](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#extend-autograd-by-defining-your-own-primitives)

I would guess tf is very similar to this.

Comment: As for indexing operation, my first guess is it's not auto differentiable. But then, maxpooling is auto differentiable, and maxpooling is just selecting a certain element, aka indexing operation. So, my 2nd guess is that indexing operation is auto differentiable, as least in theory.